# Leaflet with too many overlayed TileLayers

Tags: browser, leaflet

I am doing a leaflet map that needs to have too many other maps as overlays (more than 200!!). These are added in a manner similar to this:

```
var myBasemap = L.tileLayer(basemap_url/{z}/{x}/{y}.png, {minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 10});
map = L.map('mymap', {
    layers: [myBasemap ],
}).setView([0, 0], 2);

var myLayer_1 = L.tileLayer(url/{z}/{x}/{y}.png, {})
map.addLayer(myLayer_1)

var overlayMaps = {
    "map_id1": myLayer_1,
    "map_id2": myLayer_2,
    "map_id3": myLayer_3,
    .....
    .....
    .....
}

L.control.layers({}, overlayMaps , {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

In fact the overlayed maps are actually transparent pngs that add different content to the basemap. Also each overlay is not one single image but a pyramid or images.

The more layers are switched on the slower the webpage becomes. Having all 200 layers showing on the map at the same time makes to webpage too slow for zooming/panning. In fact performance decays when you start having more that 10 or 15 layers active on the map. I guess that happens because the browser tries to download simultaneously all those small jpgs or pngs that leaflet needs for all the overlays.

I am in full control of the basemap and all the overlays. I generate the image pyramids

Has anyone done something similar please? Any workarounds?

Would hosting each one of the overlays on its own domain (maybe on aws, googlecloud or something similar...) sound sensible?

In the attached snippet I try to demonstrate how heavy the browser becomes with an oversimplified case where I create a map with a basic tile layer for the background and then I am using the same tile layer to create 100 overlays that are added on the map as overlays.

As said earlier my overlays in a real life scenario are all different to each other (and to the base map) and they are transparent pngs that add different features/content to the webpage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #mymap {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mymap"></div>
<script>
    var minZoom = 0,
        maxZoom = 8;
    var background_map = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {minZoom: minZoom, maxZoom: maxZoom});

    map = L.map('mymap', {
        layers: [background_map],
        attributionControl: false,
    }).setView([0, 0], 2);

    // create an array of strings
    var features = [];
    var N = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        features.push("feature_" + i)
    }

    // create a dict and assign a tile layer to each feature
    var Layers_dict = {};
    features.forEach(name => {
        Layers_dict[name] = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            minZoom: minZoom,
            maxZoom: maxZoom
        });
    });

    // Add now each tile layer to the map
    features.forEach(d => {
        map.addLayer(Layers_dict[d])
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible options is to use "single tile layer". 
 Something like this https://gist.github.com/ismyrnow/5415445

Another option is use subdomains in tileUrl https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-subdomains 
 But this is more suitable for optimization on the server

Also if you have an access to tiles on sever. Your can join pngs, using for example nodejs + express, python + flask, or something else.
For example on client side you have one

```
L.tileLayer('http://YOUR_DOMAIN?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}&layers=1,2,3,4,5,6...')
```

Where "layers=1,2,3,4,5,6" is some layer identifier. Then server handles request. Joins images in ids order, and returns only one tile.
Or if there is no tiles on your server, you can also have one layer. On server side you can make requests to tile services, download and join pngs as i wrote before.